# Select where 2 columns selected are from 1 column of table but with different conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.5

Am going in circles on a query and would appreciate your help as I'm very new at this. I'm using postgre sql, version: 9.5.8

What I'm trying to do:

I want to work out the percentage of partial sales over full sales.

The part I'm completely messing up is the final select, where I am selecting the same column COUNT(sale_id) twice from the table "sale", but passing COUNT(sale_id) through 2 different conditions (one with a 'WHERE' and one without) to create 2 new columns. Do I need to join these as separate tables instead?

The desired result should be a percentage.

This is what I have (but I'm of course getting a bunch of errors):

```
SELECT ROUND(percentage_partial_sale, 1) as "percentage_partial"
FROM (
SELECT count_partial_sale / count_all_sales as percentage_partial_sale
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(sale_id) FROM sale WHERE sale.is_partial=true as "count_partial_sale", 
COUNT(sale_id) FROM sale as "total_sellouts");
```

If you could express the solution in layman's terms that would be helpful. Feel free to make changes as you wish.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN` to count conditionally:

```
select
  count(*) as all_sales,
  count(case when is_partial then 1 end) as partial_sales,
  count(case when is_partial then 1 end)::decimal / count(*)::decimal * 100.0 as ratio
from sale;
```

Comment: This works because, by default, a `CASE` expression has a value of NULL when no conditions are met, and the `COUNT()` aggregate function does not count NULL values.

Comment: @Bacon Bits: Correct. Thanks for adding this explanation.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner! I'm now getting this (which is much nearer to what I want):

`All Sales  Partial sales  Ratio
316               203               0`

There seems to be a minor issue with the percentage calculation in column 3. 

Quick calculations however show that the counts for column 1 and 2 are correct!

@BaconBits, thanks useful explanation.

Comment: Ah, okay, PostgreSQL does integer division here. I wasn't aware of this. Make this `count(case when is_partial then 1 end)::decimal / count(*)::decimal * 100.0`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Perfect, this works really well & useful explanation - thanks @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compute the average value of `is_partial` casted to `integer` (false is 0, true is 1):

```
[local] #= CREATE TABLE sale (is_partial boolean);
CREATE TABLE

[local] #= INSERT INTO sale VALUES (false), (false), (true);
INSERT 0 3

[local] #= SELECT AVG(is_partial::int) FROM sale;
┌────────────────────────┐
│          avg           │
├────────────────────────┤
│ 0.33333333333333333333 │
└────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

Time: 6,012 ms
```

---

If your use case can't be done using `AVG`, you can use `FILTER` to remove rows from an aggregate function:

```
[local] #= SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE is_partial) / COUNT(*) :: float
           FROM sale;
┌───────────────────┐
│     ?column?      │
├───────────────────┤
│ 0.333333333333333 │
└───────────────────┘
(1 row)
```